# Prepaid SIM card in France with Free mobile

Tags: france, cellphones

I bought a SIM card for 29.99 euros from [Free mobile](http://mobile.free.fr), offering unlimited data for 30 days in France. I used my credit card and they didn't take down any of my personal details. I used the address of the hostel I was staying at and probably entered my email address. I also used my nickname instead of real name because I figured its not even a mobile plan.

Now I traveled to Barcelona and used the roaming Internet (a priori included in the plan) a bit and they said I owe them more than 40 euros! Is it possible for them to charge me for it? I mean I thought it was a prepaid card and was supposed to stop when you finish using the credit! I bought the SIM from the machine in the store.

Comment: What do the Terms and Conditions say?

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I didn't manage to read the t and c I only asked them for a prepaid data and they told me to plug my details in the machine. So how do I pay for the excess? Go to a free store to pay?

Comment: @ShangLinChua you can go online. You should be able to log in (maybe they sent your login information by mail) and among the options, you should find a way to pay.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, while this offer is competitive, it has some caveats. One of the main, regarding included roaming in some countries, is that you should be a customer for more than 60 days. It is written in their [conditions](http://mobile.free.fr/docs/tarifs.pdf) (page 3, in Services inclus):

> Pass Destination (valables après 60 jours d’ancienneté au Forfait Free): ...

Regarding the prepaid nature of the plan, it is also a bit complex. While you can, through their web interface, usually prepay for international communications, it is not actually a prepaid SIM card (but a postpaid plan) and there is no limit on how much you can spend. Free mobile notifies you when you reach some amount of communications and allows itself to stop your consumption above some threshold. On page 7 of the same document:

> Communications au-delà et/ou hors forfait par ligne
>
> Appels/SMS hors forfait sur la période 
>   de facturation de plus de 
>   40€
>
> SMS+ (SMS surtaxés) de plus de
>   30€
>
> Appels/SMS depuis l’étranger et 
>   Outre-Mer hors forfait sur la période de 
>   facturation de plus de 
>   100€
>
> Internet/MMS depuis l’étranger et 
>   Outre-Mer hors forfait sur la période de 
>   facturation de plus de 
>   40€

And on the following page, the details of what Free mobile can do:

> En cas de dépassement du seuil figurant dans les tableaux ci-dessus, l’abonné est informé et invité à payer la somme correspondante depuis son 
>   Espace abonné sur mobile.free.fr. En cas de non paiement et constatation d’un accroissement du dépassement, le service pourra être restreint jusqu’à 
>   la date de la prochaine période de facturation

This also means that to pay, you should [go online](https://mobile.free.fr/moncompte/) (you should be able to log in - maybe the information to log in was sent to your hostel).